# Give every element of twodimensional array an html ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

How can i add ongoing html IDs for every element of my twodimensional array in order to access each element via css?

https://jsfiddle.net/jc22Lopj/3/

```
var list = document.getElementById('werk'),
li = document.createElement('li'),
clone;
werk.forEach(function (item) {
clone = li.cloneNode();
clone.textContent = item;
clone.className = "item"; 
list.appendChild(clone);
});
```

I would like to achieve the following structure with only one array:

```
werk = [
[TextBla1,TextBla2],
[TextBla3,TextBla4]
 ]

<ol id="werk">
<li class="item">
<div id="text1">TextBla1</div>
<div id="text2">TextBla2</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<div id="text3">TextBla3</div>
<div id="text4">TextBla4</div>
</li>
</ol>
```

I know that i can access each element like the following but i don't know how to give each element an specific ID.

```
var list = document.getElementById('werk'),
li = document.createElement('li'),
clone;
werk.forEach(function (item) {
clone = li.cloneNode();
clone.textContent = item;
clone.className = "item"; 
list.appendChild(clone);

for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  alert(item[i]); ???
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `forEach` since `item` is an array of your texts

```
var werk = [["Text1","Text2"],["Text3","Text4"]],
    list = document.getElementById('werk')

werk.forEach(function (item) {
    var clone = document.createElement('li');
    clone.className = "item"; 

    item.forEach(function(text) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute("id", text);
        div.textContent = text;
        clone.appendChild(div);
    });

    list.appendChild(clone);
});
```